# How can I find stats about all the people contributed to my posts?

Tags: discussion, answers, statistics, users

I started last week posting questions issues in this Q&A space. I had no idea how to use LaTeX. Now I learned a lot of thing thanks to many people helped me. I want to recognize your help in my thesis document, which is still in progress, so I hope more and more people will help me in the future. Is there any way to access to some kind of stats of my profile in order to cite all the authors helped me? (for example, those who comment or posted answers more frequently)

Comment: Beyond manually keeping track, the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries) is your probably best bet. If you can't find any existing queries that does what you need, you'll need to make one yourself. There are probably people who can help you with the SQL if need be, but I'm not one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While these aren't really statistics, you can find out who answered your questions using the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/). Specifically, [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/593974/who-has-answered-my-questions?UserId=119890) which lists the User ID, display name and answer/post link:

```
declare @UserId int = ##UserId##;
-- Who Has Answered My Questions?

select u.Id as [UserId], u.displayname as [Name], a.Id as [Post Link]
from users as u 
inner join posts as a on a.owneruserid = u.id and a.posttypeid = 2
where 
 (a.ParentId in (
   select id 
   from posts 
   where owneruserid = @UserId and posttypeid = 1
  ))
order by u.displayname
```

The query on SEDE requires a User ID as input and is therefore generic. However, you can find your User ID in the URL of your SE User Profile:

[image]

Note that SEDE lags the active data retrievable from the online site by about a week.

---

Alternatively, view [your questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/119890/juan-linares?tab=questions) sequentially and identify the users who provided answers.

Answer (score 5):

Most answerers on this site contribute their knowledge for the good of the community, the wish to read nicely typeset documents,  and the fun of it, and don't need individual recognition. This is what I put in the acknowledgements of a book that just came out:

> Wizards at \url{tex.stackexchange.com} were always quick to answer
>   \TeX{}nical questions.

Comment: You are right! :-)